# UWSGi, how to convert wordpress htaccess into plugin router_redirect

Tags: .htaccess, uwsgi

I would like to convert this htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

into the format required by uwsgi (as explained here: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/InternalRouting.html).

I think that I should write something like this:

```
plugins = router_redirect
route-if = exists break

route-label = index
route = .* index.php
```

But I'm not an expert of uwsgi. So an help would be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: did you resolved that problem by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

```
route-if-not = exists:${DOCUMENT_ROOT}/${PATH_INFO} setpathinfo:/index.php
```

this should be enough, or if you want to use rewrite action (it fixes SCRIPT_NAME too, but it is rarely needed on php)

```
route-if-not = exists:${DOCUMENT_ROOT}/${PATH_INFO} rewrite:/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (with fixed paths).

```
route-if = isdir:/www/application${PATH_INFO} rewrite:${PATH_INFO}/index.php
route-if-not = isfile:/www/application${PATH_INFO} rewrite:/index.php
```